# Ubuntu Not Connecting To Wi-Fi in the WH but Connects to the same network Wifi inside the office

Tags: wireless

What frequency bands does Ubuntu 20.04 support? We have more than two hundred access points in our office. Our Ubuntu laptops can connect to Wi-Fi inside the office, where there's only one access point, but they can't connect in the warehouse. Any solutions for this issue please?

Comment: Supported frequency bands are dependent on your wifi card, not just the version of Ubuntu.  Not all cards support all frequency bands.  There's also frequency restrictions in different areas and regions, so your question does NOT have enough details to be answered.  What hardware are you actually working with and what wifi cards on the hardware?  If the WH doesn't work but all other APs work i'd suggest looking to make sure the WH APs work.

Comment: "What frequency bands does Ubuntu 20.04 support?" `iwlist chan` What does this tell us? `iw reg get` and: `nmcli device wifi list` Only show the warehouse entry and redact the MAC address with xx:xx:xx.